# Convert Xaml Code Activity to C#

Tags: c#, xaml, workflow-foundation

We have been using WF Code Activity. There are few XAML files where our business logic resides.
We are in the process of re-architecting the whole application & XAML code activities need to be discarded.

I am looking out for some XAML parsers which could convert XAML code back to C# classes & methods.

I did extensive search on google & SO, but could not find any. Do you know any tool out there?

Comment: [so] is for specific code-related questions and answers. It's generally discouraged to ask for a software library or tool, especially when you haven't shown what research you've done or what you've tried already.

Comment: Couldn't you use the designer autogenerated files (g.cs)?